# How can I know if a value is invisibly returned by a function?

Tags: r

Consider the following functions

```
f1 <- function(x) {
  # do something
  x
}

f2 <- function(x) {
  # do something
  invisible(x)
}
```

Suppose I call these two functions separately and save their values.

```
a <- f1(1)
b <- f2(2)
```

Is there a way to know if `a` and `b` are invisibly returned?

The motivation is that I want to create a function in which if a value is invisibly returned the function also wants to return the value invisibly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's `withVisible`, which lets you do this:

```
> f3 = function(f, x){
   v=withVisible(f(x))
   if(v$visible){
     return(v$value)
      }else{
     return(invisible(v$value))
      }
   }
> f3(f1,1)
[1] 1
> f3(f2,1)
```

There's no way of doing it once you've got `a` and `b`, since `identical(a,b)` is `TRUE`. You can only call `withVisible` on an expression. Unless something lazy or promisy is going on.

Answer (score 2):

A possible alternative to Spacedman's (proper :-) ) solution is to put the following line inside your "outer" function.

`if (grepl('invisible', body(inner_function) ) ) return(invisible(data)) else return(data)`

Obviously this will fail if you do something creative like naming a variable "pinvisible"